Can I use remote desktop connection into a private address on a different network via RD Gateway server
I am trying to see if there is a way of having a terminal server (Windows 2019 VM) in the AWS on a private subnet and private IP address and be able to RDP by bypassing my existing RD Gateway server in order to get to the terminal server or does the IP address have to be a public IP even if you use the RD Gateway. Can this work similar to what a VPN provides if it is specified in the RemoteDesktopConnection application and configuring the RD Gateway settings
Examples below
Attempting to connect to a private IP address which is located in a different network
Using the RD Gateway as some form of VPN to be able to connect via it to reach my intended VM
Remote Desktop manager policies
CAP - All Domain users
RAP - Allowed resources are all domain computers and gateway servers.
I have purchased a public SSL Cert which currently allows me to access my collections which i have several RDSH remoteapps.
I am using the same RD Gateway address from the deployment
